# how are pointers,relations and files synced to parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse as BaaS for my android project. Facing duplication of data if I create a custom parse object and saving it as required.

Moreover I tried even extending the parse object to the required class which causes other problems !

```
 public void retrieveThreadListStoreInDB()
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Threads");
        query.include("postedBy");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Data retrieval was successfull
                    for (ParseObject parseObject : list) {
                        String title = (String) parseObject.get("threadTitle");
                        ParseUser parseUser = (ParseUser) parseObject.get("postedBy");
                        ParseFile userProfilePicture=null;
                        try
                        {
                            userProfilePicture = (ParseFile) parseUser.get("profilePicture");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e1)
                        {

                        }
                        String profilePictureUrl=null;
                        if(userProfilePicture != null) {
                             profilePictureUrl = (userProfilePicture).getUrl();
                        }
                        ParseObject threadsList = new ParseObject("ThreadsList");
                        threadsList.put("threadTitle",title);
                        if(profilePictureUrl != null) {
                            threadsList.put("postedByPicture", profilePictureUrl);
                        }
                        else {
                            threadsList.put("postedByPicture","local");
                        }

                        try {
                            threadsList.pin();
                        } catch (ParseException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("DEBUG", title);
//                        Log.d("DEBUG",profilePictureUrl);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Problem with retrieval" + e);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

> HELP ME RESOLVE DUPLICATION OF DATA AND WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO STORE FILE URL'S, POINTER RELATED INFORMATION AND RELATIONS INFORMATION ?????

Comment: Could you simply explain WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO STORE.  ie literally just explain your project in a few lines?

Comment: @Joe Blow I have a table say posts which has a pointer -> _User to retrieve profile pic(using URL + picasso) of the user  who posted something. A relation say comments -> which has the list of comments along with user pointers that point to users who commented.If still I made it difficult or unclear please ask I would be happy to explain. Thank you Joe